# How do you increment a cookie value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I am wondering how you would go about incrementing cookies (by one, just to keep in basic.)

```
var snacks = $cookies.get('fruitSnacks', 1);
snacks ++;`
```

Comment: This is like asking how to cook a restaurant. Cookies are *repositories* of values, you can't increment the whole repository.

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Get value, increment, set value. That's how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
var snacks = $cookies.get('fruitSnacks') + 1 ;


$cookies.put('fruitSnacks', snacks );
```

Comment: FInally changed . i got it got it got it :P

Answer (score 2):

#### The Angular Way

The Angular solution would be:

```
var oldVaue = $cookies.get('my-cookie');
$cookies.put('my-cookie', ++oldValue);
```

#### The jQuery Solution

With the **jquery-cookie** plugin you can handle cookies more easily:

```
var oldValue = $.cookie('my-cookie');
$.cookie('my-cookie', ++oldValue);
```

---

Now the library was superseded by **js-cookie**, here is the solution with that:

```
var oldValue = Cookies.get('my-cookie');
Cookies.set('my-cookie', ++oldValue);
```

Comment: This all makes sense to me, but not to angular. I am getting an error when I try to use '+++'. If i have them on the left of oldValue, it says "expected expression, got +." If i put them to the right, "expected expression, got )." I am assuming this is happening because of it not recognizing what I am trying to do. I will look into syntax for using that operand..

Comment: Well, I screwed that up :) Two pluses is fine.